# Difference b.w .tobeCalled vs .tobeCalled()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Wanted to know the difference b/w  .tobeCalled  and .tobeCalled().

```
  it('should emit edit as true when confirmation methods is called with true', () =>{
    component.confirmation(true)
    expect(component.confirmation).toHaveBeenCalled
    component.confirmationStatus.subscribe((res:  {edit: boolean}) => {
      expect(res).toEqual({ edit: true})
    })
  })
```

when i use the above block my code is getting covered in coverage.[code coverage image for for above code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jNW.png)

when i use the below code block its not getting coverage in the coverage. wanted to understand the difference b/w those code block.

```
it('should emit edit as true when confirmation methods is called with true', () =>{
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'confirmation')
  component.confirmation(true)
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)
  component.confirmationStatus.subscribe((res:  {edit: boolean}) => {
    expect(res).toEqual({ edit: true})
  })
})
```

[code coverage image for above code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtLPv.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `.toHaveBeenCalled` is a function that you simply don't call in your first example. So you're not actually validating the test.